# why i get the error "backend - 404 error" when trying to deploy tls ingress in kubernetes with no errors on events

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to deploy a simple Ingress service and works when is Ingress without the Secure function(tls), but when I include the cert tls it always returns me "backend - 404 error"

I already installed "cert manager", "ingress-nginx" and already checked if this install is ok

**EDIT: I explained all the steps I'm doing**

**EDIT2: I updated the cert-manager's version to v1.5.4**

these were the steps:

**1.-** install nginx controller for my ip

```
helm install bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="[MY-STATIC-IP]",rbac.create=true --generate-name
```

**2.-** Apply deployment and service (app.yaml)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: taxisbahiadeploy
  labels:
    type: endpoints-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: taxisbahiadeploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: taxisbahiadeploy
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: taxisbahiadeploy
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: taxisbahia
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: taxisbahiadeploy
```

**3.-** Configure let's encrypt

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/releases/download/v1.5.4/cert-manager.crds.yaml

kubectl create namespace cert-manager

helm repo add jetstack https://charts.jetstack.io

helm repo update

helm install \
  cert-manager \
  --namespace cert-manager \
  --version v1.5.4 \
  jetstack/cert-manager
```

**4-** Apply the Issuer (issuer.yaml)

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: 'fco@ggggg.com'
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-staging
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: 'fco@ggggg.com'
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
      - http01:
          ingress:
            class: nginx
```

**5.-** Final Step, this is the Ingress where it fails (ingress-tls.yaml)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: esp-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-staging"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - domain.com
    secretName: esp-tls
  rules:
    - host: domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: taxisbahia
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: which version of cert manage you are using and share YAML file of issuer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

i think your TLS domain part should be something like check your **host**

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.example.com
    secretName: quickstart-example-tls
```

Reference : https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/ingress/

Comment: but my domain doesn't have subdomains. why i should configure subdomains ?

Comment: Use domain at that place just shared as example check indentation

Comment: i fix the indentation but the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you are **actually visiting** https://yourapp.com

Had the same issue but then I realized I was actually trying HTTP, which is no longer available after TLS is added.